# cruise control build fails on nant task

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm looking for advise on how to diagnose a problem with our build server since I don't have any experience doing so.

```
  <message><![CDATA[External Program Failed: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com (return code was 1)]]></message>
      <location>
        <filename>C:\ContinuousIntegration\ProjectSource\apples\build\apples.build</filename>
        <linenumber>14</linenumber>


        <columnnumber>6</columnnumber>
      </location>

line 14:
    <exec basedir="${VSDir}" program="devenv.com" workingdir="..\">
      <arg value="Marble.sln" />
      <arg value="/Rebuild" />
      <arg value="${BuildConfig}" />
    </exec>
```

HOwever this line has been in there since the project was started many moons ago

Comment: The issue/problem is definitively located in your solution/project file(s). Open the referred solution/project causing that error message. I think one or more files are missing needed to compile the solution.

Comment: try adding  /Log switch/argument to the devenv.com, that should return the exact issue